# Classes composition

Tags: c++, arrays, class, composition

This is my first topic.
I would like to ask you about composition with classes in C++. I have two classes, whose one of them contains an array of the other one, for example `Teacher` and `School`.

`School` contains an array of `Teacher` and `Teacher` has two variables, like `string subject` and `int students` (number of students).

For example, the class `Teacher` has two functions: `getSubAndStud(string, int)` and `setSubAndStud()`.

I would like to ask you in which way I could initialize the array, so that the school has a number of `N` *teachers* and every *teacher* has a *subject* and a number of *students*.

Please, consider that I am a beginner, so, if you can, try to give a reply as simple as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would do this at a natural spot for this. Simply imagine that you are the user of such a system - when would you add a teacher? Of course at any time, because new teachers come and go. Therefore, you should simply give the School class some method that adds a teacher, but how depends on what the system should do. Also, I'd rename students in number_students or something like that, saves you your explanation. And I'd rename your setters and getters into something without set- and get-. Those make it less "natural" if you understand. What is "SubAndStud" supposed to be, btw? Write it out.

Comment: Also, the getter(s) will be parameterless, while the setter(s) will contain parameters

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Whenever you ask a question, take advantage of the provided formation possibilities. This makes it easier to read and understand your question (especially to distinguish between regular text and keywords/parts of code), and increases the probability to get an answer.

Comment: *"This is my first topic."* - No, it's your first question. Stack Overflow is *not* a forum! :)

Comment: If you could post your code then it will be easier to come up with suggestions

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I'm sorry for my 'mistakes' and 
oversights. I found some useful examples online and maybe now I understand. Thank you all! But, I would still have a problem and it is not the first time: using classes, I don't manage to print strings... Excuse me, if I am boring and unable. If I write the code, would you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method that takes in a variable N and constructs a School object with N teachers. Then I would create another method that instantiates a Teacher object at the smallest empty index in the Teacher array with given Subject and Student values. You could parse for an empty index by checking for NULL.